# Dynamic instanceReportSource from DLL

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

I have a compiled library of reports. What I need to do is create a variable for the library report and then assign that to the ReportDocument so I can generate a report. I want only a single aspx page, but want the instanceReportSource to be dynamic. I am using VS2013 webforms. My current way of doing this is to create a page for each report like the following.

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim instanceReportSource As New Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource()
    instanceReportSource.ReportDocument = New CTEReportsClassLibrary.rpt_fup_X0611

    instanceReportSource.Parameters.Add(New Telerik.Reporting.Parameter("Selection", Request.QueryString("Param1")))
    instanceReportSource.Parameters.Add(New Telerik.Reporting.Parameter("txtCriteria", Request.QueryString("Param2")))

    ReportViewer1.ReportSource = instanceReportSource
    ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

End Sub
```

If I am not clear what I want to do is replace the New CTEReportsClassLibrary.rpt_fup_X0611, assigned to the instanceReportSopurce.ReportDocument, with a variable that represents the report. 
I have tried a couple of ideas involving getting a string from a dll(7287958) but it kept producing nothing for a result.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, that will allow me to pass search a dll, included in the solution, so I have only a single page to display my reports rather than needing a page for each report.

```
    Private Const REPORTTYPE As String = "CTEReportsClassLibrary.{0}, CTEReportsClassLibrary"

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim strReport As String = Request.QueryString("ReportName")

    Dim T As Type = Type.GetType(String.Format(REPORTTYPE, strReport), True)

    Dim report As IReportDocument = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(T), IReportDocument)
    Dim irs = New InstanceReportSource()
    irs.Parameters.Add(New Telerik.Reporting.Parameter("Selection", Request.QueryString("Selection")))
    irs.Parameters.Add(New Telerik.Reporting.Parameter("txtCriteria", Request.QueryString("txtCriteria")))
    irs.ReportDocument = report
    Me.ReportViewer1.ReportSource = irs
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
End Sub
```